# Modeling continuous interaction effect with very small sample

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, modeling, interaction, small-sample

I have a very small data set (n = 12) of high level athletes each with a set of measurements representing technique (5 variables) and a set of measurements representing strength (3 variables), and I want to explore possible interactions between strength and technique variables in relation to a performance outcome (dependent variable). All variables are continuous.

I would like to run multiple regression models with interactions for singular combinations of technique and strength variables in relation the performance variable, but I'm really not sure if this is a reasonable thing to do with such a small sample or if I'm on a fools errand of overfitting and other problems.

Given it is impossible to increase the sample size at this stage (and the 'true' population is probably <2000), are there any other approaches better suited for looking at interactions in small samples? (Or modeling in small samples generally?)

I have a tenuous grasp on most of this stuff, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

With a sample of 12, to detect any main effect it would  have to be vast. To detect interaction effects is much more difficult than detecting main effects - see, for example: https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2018/03/15/need-16-times-sample-size-estimate-interaction-estimate-main-effect/

If you find a statistically significant interaction effect, it's likely to be (a) A false positive, and/or (b) massively overestimated.

In addition, with a sample size of 12, and 8 predictors, anything you do is going to suffer from overfitting, before you begin to model any interactions. (If you put 12 predictors into your model, you'll have perfect fit, which is meaningless).

Sorry to be negative, but you will not convince me of anything at all if you are doing regression with a sample size of 12, before you even consider interactions.

Comment: Thanks! To clarify, I meant using 1 variable from each group of independent variables at a time in a series of Y ~ X + Z + X*Z models rather than all 8 predictors in a single model, since I'm more interested in exploring specific combinations of explanatory variables and nature/direction of interactions than precise effect size estimates. But of course that doesn't change the main issue...16 times, Yikes.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @Jeremy Miles' answer.

Further to that, I suggest looking at the data from an "exploratory data analysis" approach. Visualise it, tabulate it, use models and statistics to help *explore* the data, by all means.

However, discard the idea of finding statistical significance, or precisely quantifying relationships. If you haven't gone into it with a pre-formed hypothesis, you'll be data dredging if you go hunting for significance. I am guessing that the data was not randomly selected either, which makes the generalisation of any results problematic.

tl;dr - the data can certainly tell you interesting things, and inform future studies, but you won't be able to make robust inference about the relationships at population level.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I should have maybe clarified originally that I meant more as an exploratory analysis rather than precise estimation. I'm really trying to learn a bit more about the possible relationships between combinations of independent variables in the context of the dependent variable than determine anything precise about the dependent variable if that makes sense. Do you have any recommendations for visualising/modeling interactions in exploratory data analysis?

Comment: Off the top of my head, a good starting point is using scatterplots where x is one predictor, y is the response, and colouring by another predictor to see if there's anything interesting showing up

Comment: @Braan - detecting interactions is hard at the best of times. It's hard to distinguish them from noise in large samples.